# Asp.net MVC real time application performance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i'm trying to create an asp.net mvc web application ,some pages need to show the data  in "real time" ,this data is on  a sql server database ,the data is changing always
i created a stored procedure in sql server , i call this procedure in my controller using Entity framework  linq and send the result to the browser using ajax
i used outputcashing to minimize the number of execution of the stored procedure ,
in the same controller there is multiple methode that use the same  stored procedure ,every methode execute the same procedure ,
how to emprove the performance of my application ,
is there a way to execute the stored procedure only one time for all the controller ??

this is my controller my objective is to minimize the use of the database

```
   [OutputCache(Duration = 20, VaryByParam = "*")]
public class JobsETLController : Controller
{

    private ETL_REP_MAUIEntities db = new ETL_REP_MAUIEntities();
    public   ObjectResult<BIOGetETLJobs_Result> ETLJobs;

    public JobsETLController()
    {


        ETLJobs =db.BIOGetETLJobs();


    }

    public ActionResult Indexp()
    {

        var y = from xx in ETLJobs
             where xx.etat!="Completed"
             orderby xx.etat ascending
                select xx;
        return PartialView(y);
}



    public ActionResult IndexpAll()
    {

        var y = from xx in ETLJobs
                    where xx.etat == "Completed"
                select xx;
        return PartialView(y);
    }
```

Comment: my application detect changes in some table in the database and notify the user ,the contnent of those  tables is changing continuously

Comment: Instead of using polling, think about using a "push" model that something like websockets can provide you. Your application can set up a SqlDependency. Your application will be notified whenever there is a change in the database query you're monitoring and you can use SignalR to notify your clients... http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

Comment: thank you ,i only need to update the data every 5 minute so its not really  a real time but the problem is the same controler use  a stored procedure  multiple times ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is not in a web farm (multiple servers) then you can cache the data in the Asp.net Cache (this is not output cacheing, it's data cacheing).  You simply set a 5 minute time limit on the expiration of the data (you say the data needs to update every 5 minutes) so that when a controller needs the data it first checks the cache, and if it's not there it will then execute the stored procedure.

```
MyData items;

items = (MyData)Cache["MyData"];
if(items == null)
{
   items = DoQueryToReturnItems();
   Cache.Add("MyData", items, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), ..);
}
```

It's even possible to setup the cache item to be dependent upon a SqlDependency so that when the data changes, the cache can be updated.

Comment: Thank you , that is exactly what i wanted ,but i didnt understand your example ,can you please show me how to cache   ETLJobs=db.BIOGetETLJobs(); in the example above ??

Comment: @user3489866 - I'm really not sure how it could be any clearer, I gave you an example.. You will have to figure out the rest of the values though because only you know what they should be.  Replace MyData with your own data